# JRules/WODM Dependencies or XOM Library

Tags: java, dependencies, xom, jrules

I am using a Java XOM for a Project which is supported by a library of Java Classes, I call is Util XOM. 
My understanding is that any Dependency JAR (Library) for execution of Rules is packaged and deployed into the classpath of the Rule Exeucutions Server, unlike the XOM from which the BOM (Business Object Model) is created, this XOM will be managed by the Management Stack of the Rule Execution Server, anything else that is refrenced by the Rule Project via the Build Path will be placed in the Class Path and will not be managed by the Management Stack of the Rule Execution Server. 
So the former runs in the Rule Engine, while the the later does not.

Comment: I did not understand your question - Which is working and which is not working?

Comment: I am using Java Static Methods to support the B2X, I found someone suggesting that use the Static Methods instead of writing the logic in B2X. https://ilogquery.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/to-maximize-the-performance-and-writemanage-better-business-rules-on-ilog-jrules-we-should-follow-some-best-practice-i-did-not-find-any-good-and-integrated-document-over-internet-on-ilog-best-prac/; That would mean that the Java Static Method are running outside the Rule Engine. So whatever optimizations I make to Rule Flow Tasks would have no impact on the Java Static Methods that are called from B2X.